# Selecting all from column in MySQL database table that uses WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

As per

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pages`
                      WHERE parent_id = '0'
                            AND menu_location NOT IN (main,footer)");
```

I'm trying to select all pages from database table where the parent id is 0 and the page is not in the main menu or footer menu, so I want to select all apart from if these pages are set to either of these menus.

There are multiple menu_location types so I don't believe I can use `NOT NULL` for example.

I've got a feeling I'm probably use the `NOT IN` statement out of context, but if anyone could kindly point me in the right direction on how to query the database properly, I would be very grateful.

EDIT.

```
Table: 'pages'
Table Columns: 'active', 'page_id', 'parent_id', 'order', 'site_id',
               'page_name', 'page_display_name', 'page_location', 'page_type',
               'menu_location' 
               (there are other columns but mainly for content, metadata etc).
```

I just simply want to select all pages from table apart from those which have main and footer in the menu_location column. Thanks

Comment: You should **post your table structure**, and/or a few example rows. You probably want menu_location 'main','footer' between accents, unless they refer to columns - again, without DDL we cannot know.

Comment: Just a shoot in the dark: NOT IN takes a series of values so maybe you should write the statement as `NOT IN ('main','footer')`

Comment: LOL, thanks Francesco - that as all it was - that fixed it... I was almost there! Many thanks :D

Comment: @Francesco: Please add your comment as an answer so that Geoff Jackson can accept it later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just surround main ad footer values with `''`:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pages`
                      WHERE parent_id = '0'
                            AND menu_location NOT IN ('main','footer')");
```

Answer (score 2):

simply

```
SELECT * FROM `pages`
         WHERE parent_id = '0'AND menu_location NOT IN ('main','footer')
```